# String replace on get_content in php - wordpress

Tags: php, string, wordpress

I'm using `get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );`in my theme to get the content and the title. Now I need to exclude one word from the title itself. Tried to do this with:

```
<?php
$conte =  get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

$newconte = array("word1", "word2", "word3");
$newconte2 = array("", "", "");
echo str_replace($newconte, $newconte2, $conte);
?>
```

But nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: what's the `echo` of `$conte`?

Comment: Echo is get_template_part, but the problem probably is that the output is not a string?

Comment: Guess such.. str_replace will just replace word1, word2, word3 with "" if **it actually matches any string**. The above code, with any kind of string, works, so the problem is the variable $conte :). --> http://prntscr.com/3gzoao

Comment: because `get_template_part` directly echoes content, you have to add `str_replace` in particular single post template where `the_title()` prints.

Comment: what do you suggest that I should do as solution to this problem? I used this code many times, but never with get_content.